# Trying to reset part of program, with key input

Tags: c#

I had made a short program a wile ago, for a holiday party. The idea was that everyone got a number, and I would run this program and have the random number generator pick a number. the person with the number would take there turn playing the party game.
Looking at it later on I wanted to have the program refresh with a key input, like (press R to refresh number). I used to have to keep re running the program, is there any line of C# code I could input that would allow this? I had thought about using a function to do the job, But I don't know how to go about it.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WhiteChristmas.Exe
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)



        {

            {
             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the WhiteChristmas random number Generator!!!");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("You where given a number when you walked in if your number is called then step up and play the game!");
            Console.ResetColor();

        }

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int dice = rnd.Next(1, 14);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine("The card that is picked is:" + dice);
        Console.ResetColor();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Google for c# while loop. Make a variable that is true and loop on it. When you want to exit, make it false so the loop finishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the answer of your question. Basically console app listens the key R and when it meets with the correct key. Runs the method that should return Random number. To make possible what you asked you should modify the code some like that.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.R)
        {
            RandomNumber();            }
    }

    static void RandomNumber()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int dice = rnd.Next(1, 14);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine("The card that is picked is:" + dice);
        Console.ResetColor();

    }
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.